# Debug the code from VB6 code to hit C++ code (.dsp or .dsw)

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, vb6

I have a VB6 project which is linked to Visual C++ project (.dsp or .dsw) by .DLL. It perfectly links to the C++ code and works fine. My Question is how to debug the code from this VB6 code to hit C++ code which is in (.dsp or.dsw)?

Visual C++ 6 (Copy right by 94-98) is the version.

Comment: Asked 19 years too late, hard to remember.  The vb6 app does not link C++ code, surely this is a COM component.  In your C++ project's settings you can specify what program should start when you start debugging.  That can be the compiled vb6 program.  Or, more useful, you can set it to the VB6 ide, normally c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\vb6\vb6.exe.  You can even add the .vbp as an argument.  So when you press F5, the vb6 ide starts running and you can press F5 to get your vb6 code running to trigger a breakpoint in your C++ code.

Comment: I did not get from your question - do you want to debug vb code or c++ code? Is the exe compiled as vb and dll as C++ or is the exe compiled as c++ and dll is written in vb?

Comment: @HansPassant, I want to debug from VB and then hit C++ code. I am not getting where to specify the program to start when I debug in C++? Could you please detail explain me in detail if you don't mind?

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky , "exe compiled as c++ and dll is written in vb"; this is correct.